# PHP password_verify returning false

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 projects 1 is just for checking username and password if they exist in the database,which has the function password_verify() working , and the other u can sign up and then log in, but in this 1 the function password_verify is always returning false even thought i have the same code written in both but changed the table name i will post the project, so if anyone can help me please.
I did check that it is connecting to the database normally and returning the email result correct but when it comes to comparing hashed pass with the one entered it's always false.

Index.php is the main page and contains only two php lines:

1. include("signup.php");
2. include("login.php");

**Connection.php**

```
   <?php
$server="localhost";
$db_username="myusername";
$db_password="mypassword";
$db="test_db";

$conn=mysqli_connect($server,$db_username,$db_password,$db);


if(!$conn)
    die ("Connection Failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());


?>
```

**signup.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['signup']))
{   
     function validateFormData($formData)
    {
        $formData=trim(stripcslashes(htmlspecialchars($formData)));
        return $formData;
    }

    $email=validateFormData($_POST['email']);
    $password=validateFormData($_POST['password']);

    if(!$_POST['email'])
        $error.="Please enter an email<br>";

    else if(!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        $error.="Please enter a valid email<br>";
    }

    if(!$_POST['password'])
        $error.="Please enter a password<br>";

    else
    {
        if(strlen($_POST['password'])<8)
            $error.="Password must contain at least 8 characters<br>";

        if(!preg_match('`[A-Z]`',$_POST['password']))
            $error.="Password must contain at least one capital letter<br>";
    }

    if($error)
    {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger text-center lead'><a class='close red' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</a>".$error."</div>";
    }
    else
    { 
        include('connection.php');

        $query="SELECT * FROM `diary` WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$email)."'";

        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $results=mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($results)
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger text-center lead'>This email already exists, do you want to log in?<a class='close red' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</a></div>";

        else
        {
         $selectUser=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$email);
         $hashedPass=password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
         $query="INSERT INTO `diary`(`email`, `password`) VALUES ('$selectUser','$hashedPass')";   
         mysqli_query($conn,$query);
         echo "<div class='alert alert-success text-center lead'>You've been signed up!<a class='close green' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</a></div>";

         $_SESSION['id']=mysqli_insert_id($conn);


        }
 }

}


?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['login']))
{


    function validateFormData($formData)
    {
        $formData=trim(stripcslashes(htmlspecialchars($formData)));
        return $formData;
    }


    $formEmail=validateFormData($_POST['loginEmail']);
    $formPass=validateFormData($_POST['loginPassword']);
    $newPass=password_hash($formPass,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    echo $newPass;

    include("connection.php");

    $query="Select * from diary where email='$formEmail' ";

    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

      if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        { 
            $LogEmail= $row['email'];
            $LogPass= $row['password'];
            echo "<br>".$LogPass;

        }
        if(password_verify($newPass,$LogPass))
        {
            echo "<br>Correct Password";    
        }
          else
              echo "<br>Not Correct"; 
    }


}

?>
```

> output of $newPass is :"$2y$10$dw0AtEExMc41p4nUB3W9kOOWTcNZmQev9jM4emNn7oQNODfu6Ld.q"
>
> output of $LogPass is : "$2y$10$biz6Z5nxsMZXNf7p3ebqw.pksPb1VhWEmoan776rMqOC7VcFRQbrK"

**Index**

```
<?php

include("signup.php");
include("login.php");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Secret Diary</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
      <form class="form-horizontal emailForm" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
          <legend><h1 class="text-center">Sign Up</h1></legend>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email" >Email:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="email" class="form-control" style="width:90%" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email"  name="email" value="<?php echo addslashes($_POST['email']);?>">   
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" style="width:90%" id="pwd" placeholder="Password" name="password">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success " id="btnClick" name="signup">Sign Up</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form><!--SIGN UP-->

         <form class="form-horizontal emailForm" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
          <legend><h1 class="text-center">Log In</h1></legend>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="LogInEmail" >Email:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="email" class="form-control" style="width:90%" id="LogInEmail" placeholder="Enter Email"  name="loginEmail" value="<?php echo addslashes($_POST['loginEmail']);?>">   
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="LogInPassword">Password:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" style="width:90%" id="LogInPassword" placeholder="Password" name="loginPassword">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success " id="btnClick" name="login">Log In</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form><!--LOG IN-->
</div>
    <script src="js/JQuery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried it without this function but still the same

Comment: I can send u this project it only has sign up and log in maybe you can get a better knowledge on what the problem might be

Comment: the hash is for the password i did check

Comment: When the user signs up the password is hashed and stored in the database , and when he wants to log in i take the pass from the <input> and compare it with the hashed one from the database using password_verify, but it's always returning false, and yes it gives the hash value of $formPass

Comment: yeah i deleted all records and started again just added two records

Comment: I'm new to this website so i don't know exactly how to update my question but did write it again it is down below , and it has two outputs i don't know if this is what you meant

Comment: ok check them now if this is what u asked for

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it worked when i removed the hash from the password that I'm trying to verify .

Comment: Great, I'll add that to the answer I had. Please accept it in a few minutes after update.

Comment: No I thought i can have both but now i changed it to the last one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You overwrite your `$password` when you include your dbconnection.

```
include('connection.php');
```

has:

```
$password="mypassword";
```

Previously you set:

```
$password=validateFormData($_POST['password']);
```

so your hashed password is not the user's password, but your DB password.

I would prefix all DB credentials variables with `db_`. So your database password variable would then be `$db_password`. This will allow you to have distinct variables throughout your project (I'd think).

Additionally you should be using `$formPass`, not `$newpass`. The `$newpass` is going to be double hashed at the `verify` function.

```
$formEmail=validateFormData($_POST['loginEmail']);
$formPass=validateFormData($_POST['loginPassword']);
$newPass=password_hash($formPass,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

so change:

```
if(password_verify($newPass,$LogPass))
```

to:

```
if(password_verify($formPass, $LogPass))
```

Comment: okay i changed the variable password to db_password and in login.php i hashed the form data and echo it it gave "$2y$10$boLdsZ6VRceuEf4x7x8II.in9yHN0nCDFLABEU5xJg.8BjvVvB6uC"

Comment: and the $LogPass echo "$2y$10$biz6Z5nxsMZXNf7p3ebqw.pksPb1VhWEmoan776rMqOC7VcFRQbrK" so they are different

Comment: sorry , hashed $formPass not form data

Answer (score 0):

`password_verify` expects the cleartext password as its first argument. To fix your code, remove this line:

```
$newPass=password_hash($formPass,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

And change this line:

```
if(password_verify($newPass,$LogPass))
```

To the following:

```
if(password_verify($formPass,$LogPass))
```

Comment: Hey @chris85 Guess I arrived while the question was in flux. No one had written an answer when I posted this and most of the comments discussion was hidden. I just saw the problem in `login.php` and wrote about it. didn't even realize until just now (upon reading your answer) that there were other issues that had been fixed before my arrival (such as the db password overwrite)